# Gridview show controls (labels, buttons, textfields) even if Datasource is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

How can I show my controls even if my table columns are null using gridview? All I know is                                  ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"

Comment: textbox1.Visible = true; in code behind

Comment: Didn't work sir. This time I need to show controls :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If datasource of gridview is null, you can create a temporery datatable and assign it as a datasuource of gridview.

```
if (GridView1.DataSource == null)
    {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            GridView1.DataSource=dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try all your suggestions. Though I'm getting an error with dtTemp, about it "not existing in the current context". :(

Comment: use GridView1.DataSource= dt;

Comment: All good I've done editing it :D
New problem is how to declare checkbox. :(

Answer (score 1):

If your data is NULL then there is no data to show. In order to show the controls, you need to have data. 
I'd try to create a dummy row if the db returns null.

```
if(db.rows.count < 1)
{ 
    //add a row with dummy values
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this too, might help in the future. :D

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(num_rows);
```

Comment: your code applicable for window base but question is about web